# php class/function not getting correct id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a comments system in php/jscript for photos and is working fine until I exit the block preview where the image and the comments are or click next/previous.

The problem is, while I'm in the block I can comment and the saved (db) id is correct, but if I exit or click the next/previous button the saved id is different. I'm talking about the photo id and the comment(s) belonging to that id.

I just noticed that the id is the number of posts that I made the first time (without closing or changing the image) less 1. For example, a photo without comments: I make 5 comments without closing or changing the current photo, then when I change it or close it and I open it again and make a comment, the saved id will be the number of the firsts post less 1. In this case I'll see in the comments table photo_id = 4 instead of the correct photo id, but the first 5 comments will have the real photo id.

This is the function that saves the comments into db, it's inside `CMyComments` class:

```
function acceptComment() {
    $iItemId = (int)$_POST['id']; // prepare necessary information
    $sIp = $this->getVisitorIP();
    $sName = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->escape(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
    $sText = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->escape(strip_tags($_POST['text']));

    if ($sName && $sText) {
        // check - if there is any recent post from you or not
        $iOldId = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->getOne("SELECT `c_item_id` FROM `s281_items_cmts` WHERE `c_item_id` = '{$iItemId}' AND `c_ip` = '{$sIp}' AND `c_when` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1 LIMIT 1");
        if (! $iOldId) {
            // if everything is fine - allow to add comment
            $GLOBALS['MySQL']->res("INSERT INTO `s281_items_cmts` SET `c_item_id` = '{$iItemId}', `c_ip` = '{$sIp}', `c_when` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), `c_name` = '{$sName}', `c_text` = '{$sText}'");
            $GLOBALS['MySQL']->res("UPDATE `user_uploads` SET `comments_count` = `comments_count` + 1 WHERE `id` = '{$iItemId}'");

            // and print out all comments
            $sOut = '';
            $aComments = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->getAll("SELECT * FROM `s281_items_cmts` WHERE `c_item_id` = '{$iItemId}' ORDER BY `c_when` DESC");
            foreach ($aComments as $i => $aCmtsInfo) {
                $sWhen = date('F j, Y H:i', $aCmtsInfo['c_when']);
                $sOut .= <<<EOF
                            <div class="comment" id="{$aCmtsInfo['c_id']}">
                                <p>Comment from {$aCmtsInfo['c_name']} <span>({$sWhen})</span>:</p>
                                <p>{$aCmtsInfo['c_text']}</p>
                            </div>
EOF;
            }
            return $sOut;
        } else return 1;
    }        
}
```

This is the javascript function:

```
// submit comment
function submitComment(id) {
    var sName = $('#name').val();
    var sText = $('#text').val();

    if (sName && sText) {
        $.post('/views/site/reto.php', { action: 'accept_comment', name: sName, text: sText, id: id }, 
            function(data){ 
                if (data != '1') {
                    $('#comments_list').fadeOut(1000, function () {
                        //$('#name').val() = "";
                        //$('#text').val() = "";
                        $(this).html(data);
                        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#comments_warning2').fadeIn(1000, function () {
                        $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        $('#comments_warning1').fadeIn(1000, function () { 
            $(this).fadeOut(1000); 
        }); 
    }
};
```

And this is the photo script:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'get_info' && (int)$_POST['id'] > 0) {

    require_once('classes/CMySQL.php'); // include service classes to work with database and comments
    require_once('classes/CMyComments.php');

    // get photo info
    $iPid = (int)$_POST['id'];
    $aImageInfo = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->getRow("SELECT * FROM `user_uploads` WHERE `id` = '{$iPid}'");

    // prepare comments
    $sCommentsBlock = $GLOBALS['MyComments']->getComments($iPid);

    $aItems = $GLOBALS['MySQL']->getAll("SELECT * FROM `user_uploads` ORDER by `up_time` DESC"); // get photos info

    // Prev & Next navigation
    $sNext = $sPrev = '';
    $iPrev = (int)$GLOBALS['MySQL']->getOne("SELECT `id` FROM `user_uploads` WHERE `id` < '{$iPid}' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
    $iNext = (int)$GLOBALS['MySQL']->getOne("SELECT `id` FROM `user_uploads` WHERE `id` > '{$iPid}' ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1");
    $sPrevBtn = ($iPrev) ? '<div class="preview_prev" onclick="getPhotoPreviewAjx(\''.$iPrev.'\')"><img src="/images/prev.png" alt="prev" /></div>' : '';
    $sNextBtn = ($iNext) ? '<div class="preview_next" onclick="getPhotoPreviewAjx(\''.$iNext.'\')"><img src="/images/next.png" alt="next" /></div>' : '';

    require_once('classes/Services_JSON.php');
    $oJson = new Services_JSON();
    header('Content-Type:text/javascript');
    echo $oJson->encode(array(
        'data1' => '<img class="fileUnitSpacer" src="/images/user_uploads/'. $aImageInfo['filename'] .'">' . $sPrevBtn . $sNextBtn,
        'data2' => $sCommentsBlock,
    ));
    exit;
}
```

When I open again the photo, it shows the comments that have the correct id (in db) but if a comment again the displayed comments will be those that have the incorrect id, only those.

What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the problem with the Javascript or the PHP code? If you don't know, that's the first thing I'd do to track down the issue.

Comment: Yes, but how can I know that? I tried the firefox console but nothing no errors showed and same for php_error_log.

Answer (score 0):

> To get the where the error is comming up.
>    Please check with breakpoints for the JS file with keeping breakpoint for the submitComment function check if the return of the function is updated with correct value in JS or PHP